# mongodb aggregate with $match and unwind

Tags: arrays, mongodb

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387072/mongodb-retrieve-array-subset) question...

I am trying to make an aggregate function and filter my array based on values in subarray. Currently my array structure is as follows:

```
'id':1,
'data': {
   'value':1    
 }
'id':2,
'data': {
   'value':1    
 }
'id':3,
'data': {
   'value':2    
 }
```

So I need to get all items where data.value is 1. Currently in order to do this I have to do the following:

```
db.ids.aggregate([
{$match:{id:{$exists:true}}}, //some more matching conditions here...
{$unwind:'$data'},
{$match:{'data.value':1}}//need to get rid of this and move it to the first $match
```

So the question is can I get rid of the second $match and put my subarray filter condition into the first match? I tried to do that but it did not work and returned the whole document. I really need to filter my array based on subarray value because my db would become very large and I dont want $unwind on the whole bunch of documents.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you please add an example of a whole document as it is currently not clear (at least not to me) how your document looks like - I am currently not sure whether your shown data should represent 3 docs or one doc with a nested array containing those 3 sub docs.

Answer (score 0):

You could add multiple conditions in the first match itself.

```
db.ids.aggregate([
  {$match:{id:{$exists:true}, "data.value": 1}}
])
```

and then do your unwind.

Comment: that also did not help unfortunately. I also tried to add multiple conditions with $and, but it did not work either.

Comment: You will need to replace data.value with whatever is in your schema.
I am looking at your linked question, and in it, the data array is at services.TCP80.data. Here, you mention items in the data array, but it doesn't look like an array. Might help if you can provide a sample document.

Answer (score -1):

try below:

```
 db.ids.aggregate([
{$match:{id:{$exists:true}}, 'data.value':1},
{$unwind:'$data'}
```

Comment: I have already tried that and it did not help. Still it returned all the data without filter. It filters only when $match is used after $unwind

Comment: @Jack you mean it's returning data which has value 2 i.e. data.value: 2 records?

Comment: yes, it also returns data.value:2 though I explicitly showed that I need only 'data.value':1. Thats the case

Comment: I don't know why it's behaving differently as at my side it is only fetching data.value: 1 only.